# How to loop all elements that match the same xPath - Java

Tags: java, xpath

Hi all I have something like the following xml:

```
<something>
 <fruit>
 <colour>red</colour>
 </fruit>
 <fruit>
 <colour>blue</colour>
 </fruit>
 <fruit>
 <colour>green</colour>
 </fruit>
</something>
```

and currently I access the node value like so:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String nodeValue = (String) xPath.evaluate("something/fruit/colour", xmlDocument, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

I am wondering how I can make it so that I loop through each matching path?

so something like:

```
foreach matching path  {
// Print value of that path 
}
```

Comment: You need something like this? https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath) to help.

Below I have created a small working example, with `fruits.xml` holding your XML example.

```
    FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(new File("fruits.xml"));
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(fileIS);
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/something/fruit/colour";
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.print(node.getTextContent());
    }
```

This will produce:

> red
> blue
> green

Comment: Thanks for your help. The article was also very useful :)